# Creating specific Report

Tags: civireport

How would we go about achieving the following report results? (I have looked at the report page but haven’t worked with this yet)

I have pasted a snippet below.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Zephyr,

The report you looking for is not available in CiviCRM. You will need to program to add such report through an [extension](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/extensions/civix/#generate-report).

Thanks

Pradeep

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Pradeep's answer, some folks will use a third-party business intelligence (BI) tool to achieve this.  Google Data Studio, Tableau and Pentaho Data Suite are all viable options.  However, this often requires advanced configuration, and just shifts the programming burden from CiviCRM/PHP to the BI tool.